# Conversion operator for class type?

Tags: c++, casting, c++11, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

For arithmetic types `T`, one can have a class that contains a conversion operator :

```
template <typename T>
class Value
{
    constexpr operator T() const;
};
```

Is this `operator` is available for all types (as an example, is it working for `T = std::vector<double>`?) and if not, for what types *does* it work?

Comment: Have you experimented with different values of `T`? What are the results?

Comment: Note that the conversion operator is only defined for *the same* T than your class instance has. So for example, a `Value<int>` has the conversion operator for `int`, nothing more.

Comment: i think it should be working for any `T`, maybe there are situations where you can't expect an implicit conversion to be performed at all (e.g. narrowing conversions in an initializer list), but that's not because of any peculiarity of the target type itself. so in conclusion i am tempted to answer "yes", but the 1% of doubt in my mind stops me from doing it. oh, `std::inizialier_list<X>` would likely not be an eligible `T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type is a type: there are very few things that you can do with
a built-in type, and not with a appropriately defined user
defined type.  In this case, about the only real requirement is
that the type be copyable (and that you have some way of
constructing it in the implementation).

And BTW, I think you meant:

```
class Value
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr operator T() const;
};
```

(except that for a lot of types, it won't really be usable as
a `const`, `constexpr` or no).